# EclipseLink Fech Join return empty result when there are no children

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I have two tables, Parent and Child, while of course the Parent can have many Children.

Using JPA and Eclipselink, I want to get the parent and all his children in one request.

I tried with the hints this way:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Parent.findWithChildren", query = "SELECT m FROM Parent m WHERE m.id=:id",
        hints = {
            @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.FETCH, value = "m.childList"),
        }
)
```

Which is working well, and produces one request to get all.
The request is similar to:

```
 SELECT * FROM parent, child where ....
```

You see, there is no explicit "join" keyword.

However, the problem that in case the parent have no children yet, it does not return the parent at all, and it returns and empty result instead. How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#FETCH) explains it all:

> This uses an INNER join and will filter null or empty values, see LEFT_FETCH for outer joins.

So, use LEFT_FETCH instead, or better, use the standard JPQL query, which doesn't need any proprietary query hint:

```
select m from Parent m left join fetch m.childList where m.id = :id
```